# React Datepicker warning about Date-fns, parseISO() problem

Tags: react-hook-form, date-fns, react-datepicker

I am using React Datepicker with React Hook Form. I need some components must be only year and month and I use `showMonthYearPicker` props. But I get a warning if I write it.

```
Starting with v2.0.0-beta.1 date-fns doesn't accept strings as date arguments. 
Please use `parseISO` to parse strings.

Error
    at toDate (index.js:48:20)
    at getMonth (index.js:22:14)
    at o.getMonthClassNames
```

I can not remove this warning.

My component

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import az from 'date-fns/locale/az';
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns';

import { ReactComponent as Calendar } from '@/assets/images/calendarIcon.svg';

const DatePickerComponent = ({
  title,
  control,
  name,
  size,
  defaultValue,
  disabled = false,
  myChange,
  value,
  isClearable = false,
  showMonthYearPicker,
}) => {
  const datePickerClass = disabled ? 'datePicker disabled' : 'datePicker enabled';

  const CustomInput = forwardRef(({ value, onClick }, ref) => (
    <div className="custom-input-container">
      <button onClick={onClick} type="button">
        <Calendar />
      </button>
      <input ref={ref} type="text" readOnly value={value} onClick={onClick} placeholder="" />
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>{title}</label>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <DatePicker
            value={value}
            placeholderText="dd-mm-yyyy"
            customInput={<CustomInput />}
            onChange={(date) => {
              if (myChange) myChange(date);
              field.onChange(date);
            }}
            selected={field.value}
            dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
            disabled={disabled}
            wrapperClassName={`datePicker ${datePickerClass} ${size === 'small' ? 'small' : size === 'medium' ? 'medium' : 'large'}`}
            showMonthDropdown
            showYearDropdown
            showMonthYearPicker={showMonthYearPicker ? true : false}
            calendarStartDay={1}
            dropdownMode="select"
            locale={az}
            isClearable={isClearable}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DatePickerComponent;
```

Parent component

```
   {fields.map((field, index) => (
            <Fragment key={field.id}>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <DatePickerComponent
                  title="Tutulacağı ay"
                  value={moment(watch(`items[${index}].date`)).format('MMMM Y')}
                  name={`items[${index}].date`}
                  control={control}
                  size="medium"
                  showMonthYearPicker={true}
                />
              </Grid>
       </Fragment>
          ))}
```

If I write like this I get an error `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value`

```
   onChange={(date) => {
              if (myChange) myChange(date);
              field.onChange(parseISO(date));
            }}
```